# how to resolve 'RTC is Reset,Bios setup Default has been loaded' error?

Tags: boot, bios

My computer sometimes boots up automatically and and shows this error, and if I press `F1` my Grub loads.

if I turn it on my self then it doesn't give me this error.

the problem is sometimes it happens in the middle of the night or when i'm not Around, and while my computer is showing this error the CPU fan is running at 100%. i don't think that's good for hardware.

i'm only using Ubuntu so this can't be a Windows issue
but if it's not an Ubuntu issue and has to do something with my hardware then please point me in the right direction and i'll ask my question there

[image: Error Picture]

Comment: RTC = Real time clock. Perhaps you need to replace the battery on the motherboard.

Comment: @Jos oh, it was way off topic